# Text file does not open

Tags: 16.04, text-processing, clamav

Scanning via

```
sudo date >> clam &&
    clamscan -r  -i --detect-pua --remove /home >> clam &&
    date >> clam
```

Returns a file that does not open

Error message:

```
Could not open the file /home/alaa/clam.
pluma has not been able to detect the character encoding.
Please check that you are not trying to open a binary file.
Select a character encoding from the menu and try again.
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
4.15.0-39-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 24 17:05:15 UTC 2018 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux
```

[text file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CrV3Zz8cXCokkpPv3GQdVg4xHWfimbcz)

Comment: Must be the `clamscan` command in the middle. What is the output of `clamscan -r -i --detect-pua --remove /home` ? Oh wait. You redirected all output to a file called `clam`. Was there a binary file called `clam` in that same directory when you ran that command?

Comment: Post the output of `file clam`

Comment: What you mean by the output of file clam any specific command?  Have been redirecting output of clamscan this way for sometime.

Comment: @user176105 Yes, `file` is a command that detects filetype. I just posted an answer that shows what I mean. You can read `man file` for more info.

Comment: $ file clam
clam: data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 542 has a bunch of null bytes. I don't know why, but I can tell you how I figured it out and how to fix it.

---

First I downloaded the file from your link, then ran `file clam`, which said `clam: data`, so that means it contains bytes/characters that shouldn't be in a UTF-8 text file, otherwise it would say `UTF-8 Unicode text`.

Then I wrote this pipeline to find non-printing characters:

```
< clam python3 -c 'import sys; [print(repr(line.rstrip("\n"))) for line in sys.stdin]' |
    grep -n '\\'
```

Output (where `\x00` represents a null byte):

```
542:'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00ن يول  2 11:58:51 EET 2018'
```

**Explanation**:

- `< clam` - Read `clam` via stdin.
- `python3` - Python 3 supports Unicode natively, so it's a good tool for the job.
- `[... for line in sys.stdin]` - Iterate over each line of stdin.
- `print(repr(line.rstrip("\n")))` - Print a representation of each line, excluding the trailing newline. Non-printing characters will be represented by a backslash sequence.
- `grep -n '\\'` - Print lines containing backslashes plus the line number.

Note this is a quick and dirty way to do this.

---

To fix it, simply delete the null bytes. `tr` is handy for this:

```
tr -d '\0' < clam > clam.txt
```

Then confirm the output file is good with `file clam.txt`. It says `clam.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text`, so yes, it's good.

Comment: That was good newly created file clam.txt opened okay.

Comment: How to avoid this from happening again.

Comment: @user176105 I don't know why it happened in the first place, so I couldn't tell you, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it more safely : `ascii2uni clam > clam.txt`

Comment: Add details why was the other answer unsafe?

Comment: It's an *answer*, but it could certainly use some more detail as mentioned in the other comments.